# Identify if dot.net 4.5 is installed & install it if not

Tags: .net, batch-file

I need to identify if dot.net 4.5 is installed and if it isn't then install it.  I can't check to see if the directory is present as it uses the same one as 4.0.  I have found that if I put the following in a .bat file it displays the version.

**wmic /namespace:\root\cimv2 path win32_product where "name like '%%.NET%%'" get version**

but I need to do this in some sort of if statement so that I can then run the exe if it is false.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx) MSDN article.

REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" /s|FIND " Version"|FIND "4.5."||ECHO Not found! Start setup!

This command will check registry sub keys for "Version" "4.5". You can replace `ECHO ...` with install command, or `GOTO` in a batch for further processing..

Answer (score 2):

Bet you it doesn't display the version. This does

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_product where "name like '%%.NET%%'" get version
```

Look before the root word.

Then use the Findstr command errorlevel to decide what to do.

```
(wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_product where "name like '%%.NET%%'" get version|findstr /c:"4.5"
If not errorlevel 1 echo sucess&goto :eof)
```

Added space before the get (my space key is faulty).